# Left column fixed until right column is scrollable

Tags: scroll

As in [this web page](http://melaniedaveid.com/), I would like to have a section in my layout that consists of 2 columns: when the scrollTop reaches the upper margin of the section, the left column stays fixed and the right column moves vertically until its lower margin appears. From here downwards they can both move normally.

How did she does it? can anybody help me?

Comment: Seems like its all in order

Comment: Uhmm..the question is "How did she does it?".
I would like to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/perminder-klair/pen/tdzue

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log( "document ready!" );

  var $sticky = $('.sticky');
  var $stickyrStopper = $('.sticky-stopper');
  if (!!$sticky.offset()) { // make sure ".sticky" element exists

    var generalSidebarHeight = $sticky.innerHeight();
    var stickyTop = $sticky.offset().top;
    var stickOffset = 0;
    var stickyStopperPosition = $stickyrStopper.offset().top;
    var stopPoint = stickyStopperPosition - generalSidebarHeight - stickOffset;
    var diff = stopPoint + stickOffset;

    $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
      var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number

      if (stopPoint < windowTop) {
          $sticky.css({ position: 'absolute', top: diff });
      } else if (stickyTop < windowTop+stickOffset) {
          $sticky.css({ position: 'fixed', top: stickOffset });
      } else {
          $sticky.css({position: 'absolute', top: 'initial'});
      }
    });

  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 90px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.content {
  float: right;
  width: 640px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 800px;
}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 820px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    This is header
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar sticky">
    This is side bar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    This is main content
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="sticky-stopper"></div>
    This is my footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check this. it swill help you.

Comment: Thanks for answering Ram. I have applied your code to my layout and I am seeing a strange behavior.

https://codepen.io/Stonino82/pen/ypxOBx